# Fixtures organization

Tags: symfony, environment, fixtures

How do you organize your fixtures inside a Symfony2 project. Is there a standard you can respect so that when you use the `doctrine:fixtures:load --env=environment` command, only fixtures related to the `environment` environment are used ? This could be useful because fixtures for production are very likely to be different from fixtures for test.

Comment: why would you want to run fixtures in production? they're used for tests, so only test environment.

Comment: @Inori: no, they're not used only for tests. See first § of [this page](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html) why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current fixtures bundle does not handle this.
If you want to load only certain fixtures, you must specify them using the `--fixtures` repeatable option:

```
./app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=/path/to/fixtures1 --fixtures=/path/to/fixtures2
```

Anyway, in your tests, I advise you to load your fixtures eagerly, reseting your database before each test.

Comment: I disagree with your last remark, I understand why it would be more convenient but tests should be fast. Another solution would be to use transactions and rollback add the end of each test, but I don't know if it is possible. +1 for the rest of your question though.

Comment: You're right with the speed. I generally separate unit & functional tests using PHPUnit tags so I still can run my unit tests very fast.

Answer (score 7):

Make your fixture implement `ContainerAwareInterface` and inside its `load` method, you can get the environment with:

```
$this->container->get('kernel')->getEnvironment();
```